# Authorship for scripts in Shortcuts app

Tags: ios, privacy, shortcuts-app

Do the scripts that I create in iOS Shortcuts app contain information on who created them? If so, is there a way to share a shortcut I created without disclosing my authorship?

Does it depend on how I share the shortcut: as a file / as iCloud link or otherwise?